# Check if a string conains a specific word

Tags: php, if-statement, wpallimport

I need to check if an URL address contains some text. so I created this code.

```
function url_mapping_name( $urlname ) {
    if (str_contains($urlname, 'amazon.de')) {
    echo "amazon;
}
if (str_contains($urlname, 'brickset')) {
    echo 'brickset';
} else {
    echo 'no URL';
}
```

I am trying to say.
Look for "amazon.de" in $urlname, if the URL contains amazon.de return amazon, if the URL contains brickset.com return brickset, if nothing found return no URL

But something is wrong and I do know where I did a mistake

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: As you can tell from the highlighting here, `"amazon;` is missing the closing quote

Comment: __What exactly__ is wrong?

Comment: It's going to hit both if blocks, so if it's amazon, it will also hit `no URL`. The second if should be an `else if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

> echo 'amazon';

is missing a quotation mark. Note the color coding changes. That is usually caused by a missing quotation mark.

Assuming by "return" you mean having the function assign that value to a variable, all the output strings should be

> return 'string';

instead of

> echo 'string';

A potential additional issue is having 2 if statements instead of using else if. If you do intent to echo the strings instead of returning them, it should be like this so when it's equal to 'amazon' it doesn't also echo 'no url'

```
function url_mapping_name( $urlname ) {
     if (str_contains($urlname, 'amazon')) {
        echo 'amazon';
     } else if (str_contains($urlname, 'brickset')) {
        echo 'brickset';
     } else {
          echo 'no URL';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I used the following improvements and it works now.

1. I fixed the closing quote
2. replaced echo with return
3. used elseif - it returned "amazonno URL" before as @aynber wrote

```
function url_mapping_name( $urlname ) {
    if (str_contains($urlname, 'amazon.de')) {
    return 'amazon';
}
elseif (str_contains($urlname, 'brickset')) {
    return 'brickset';
} else {
    return 'no URL';
}
}
```

Thank you very much for helping me.